# how to inspect gwt screen?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

GWT screens are composed of a hierarchy of Widgets each implemented by various application classes. In order to maintain (add/change) these screens it is required to understand its structure, namely to discover which screen element is rendered by which Widget implementation.

Currently, I am trying to read the "suspected" class source while peeking at the DOM structure of the screen.

I am looking for a tool, or method, to aid with discovering which Widget class renders a specific screen element.

Such a tool would monitor the mouse position on screen and provide the class name of the hovered element (for example, in a tooltip).

Alternatively, I would be happy to find a programming method that allows adding a generic mouse event handler, most desirable to the RootPanel, further displaying the class name of currently hovered element.

Comment: The best thing to do is to add IDs to your ui.xml (or debugId if you only want them in dev, using .ensureDebugId() method).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AFAIK ,as of now there is no such tool for GWT( will be more happy if any ) .

As on `browser side`  there is no such information available related to `class files of java` available since it compiled to javascript.

So , what's the fix??

Though very common and tradational.

1)Proper naming conventions

2)Proper `package structure`

3)Documentation etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [GWT-Instrumental](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-instrumental/) project for an example of how this can be achieved. This is not a new project and may need to be updated to be properly useful in some cases, but seems to work with GWT 2.4 and GWT 2.5.1 projects just fine. The Inspector bookmarklet/instructions can be found at http://gwt-instrumental.googlecode.com/svn/latest/inspectorwidget/index.html.

This isn't doing *exactly* what you are describing, but could be modified fairly simply. What it does do is this:

- When launched (or refreshed), look at every element on the page to see what widget might be references, and what css classes it has, what id it has, and what DOM events are sunk on it.
- When expanded, renders a firebug-like tree of the DOM elements in the body, along with the details mentioned above
- When the user hovers over a element in the tree, draws a yellow overlay on where that item is drawn on the page so you can find it.